# Drawable array from xml into int for recycler adapter

Tags: android, int, drawable, android-recyclerview

This is one of many arrays I put into .xml

```
<array name="clrs">
        <item>@drawable/red_bg</item>
        <item>@drawable/yellow_bg</item>
        <item>@drawable/green_bg</item>
        <item>@drawable/white_bg</item>
        <item>@drawable/white_bg</item>
        <item>@drawable/white_bg</item>
    </array>
```

when I use `getResources().getIntArray(R.array.clrs);` result is 0 `int` 
On the official android developers it says to use it like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(0);
```

but then the type is `drawable` and I need an `int` for my recycler adapter

```
setImageResource(myCustomItem.getImage());//must be int
```

How do I change the type or use different method to show image on my cardview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer, but I didn't try it. Maybe it works but I found a better, and probably intended solution. Instead of using `setImageResource()` I'm using `setImageDrawable()`

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <integer-array name="random_imgs">
    <item>@drawable/red_bg</item>
    <item>@drawable/yellow_bg</item>
    <item>@drawable/green_bg</item>
    <item>@drawable/white_bg</item>
    <item>@drawable/white_bg</item>
    <item>@drawable/white_bg</item>
  </integer-array>
```

Then in your activity, access them like so:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);

// get resource ID by index
imgs.getResourceId(i, -1)

// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));

// recycle the array
imgs.recycle();
```

Hope it helps.